# Do I need to clear all definitions whenever I experiment with new parameter values?

Tags: clear

Do I have to clear all my definitions whenever I experiment with different parameter values for my model? For example, I have a simple model as follows:

```
w[t_]:=w[t]=w[t-1]+h
w[0]=0    
h = 5
```

I want to do:

```
Table[w[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

with varying h. But every time I change h, I have to clear the definitions with

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Otherwise, the result for w[t] remains the same. This practice is ok with this simple model. But when the model is pretty big, it really is time-consuming. I was expecting to get a new result directly by changing h. Any helpful comments in this direction?

Comment: Could you use w[t_,h_] instead of setting h afterward ?

Comment: @WilliamBriand, thanks. I can try. But my actual model is pretty big with so many parameters. So it would be impossible to put all of them into the bracket.

Comment: @Kuba, thanks. I think that's what I did. You can see h gets value at the end.

Comment: Enclosing things in `Dynamic` allow for post hoc update of variables -- though it may make it considerably slower to run.

Answer (score 1):

You could just clear the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DownValues.html) you don't want.

```
w[t_] := w[t] = w[t - 1] + h
w[0] = 0;

Table[DownValues[w] = Drop[DownValues[w], {2, -2}]; Table[w[t], {t, 0, 3}], {h, 2, 5}]
```

> ```
> {{0, 2, 4, 6}, {0, 3, 6, 9}, {0, 4, 8, 12}, {0, 5, 10, 15}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much, m_goldberg. But it seems quite complicated. In fact, I was moving over from R. With R, you just change h directly and you will have new results for w[t]. I was expecting something similar to this. It seems R is much more convenience than Mathematica for experimenting with a dynamic model with many variables and parameters. Is it true?